# How to make multicolumn element enlarge its parent in width?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a multicolumn menu with CSS3 multicolumn capabilities:

```
  -webkit-column-width: 165px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
```

Here is what I get:

[image: Menu]

I was hoping the multicolumn would enlarge its parent width accordingly but it only makes it one-column wide so the rest goes out of the menu.
I tried to get width of it with jQuery but it also shows only the width of one column.
Is there a way I can fix it?

**SOLUTION:** I have found a similar question and a solution that worked for me here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8780501/135829.